# Is it possible to set up Amazon advertising with the Media module?

Tags: media, 9

I have a Drupal 9 site with the Media module enabled.

I have subscribed to the Amazon partner program.

Is there a solution to display Amazon iframe in Drupal? I am thinking of the Media module.

Many websites display the product name with the updated price in real time. I did not find anything to fire this.

My question :

Is it possible to set up Amazon advertising with Drupal 9 and the Media module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the media module for this because eventually your needs may get more complex and you'll want access to the [Amazon Product Advertising SDK](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/quick-start/using-sdk.html).

Thankfully there's a module that supports this already, [Amazon Product Advertising](https://www.drupal.org/project/amazon_pa).

It does not yet have a stable release for D9, but it's in active development (new beta released last week).

Comment: Yes, but the module is not ready. I would have liked to add a taxonomy tags field in a media type to display contextual affiliation with block Views.

Comment: @Mathieu I don't understand what you want to do then.  If you just want to use the `<iframe>` Amazon gives you in the affiliate UI on Amazon.com, you can cut-and-paste that code into Drupal anywhere you have `Full HTML` enabled, including node bodies, taxonomy term fields, etc.  There's no special reason to use media in that case.

Comment: Ok thank you, but the problem with this solution is that Amazon loads cookies on my domain, so it forces me to ask for consent from visitors https://ibb.co/fDHZyHw

Comment: @Mathieu If you have a requirement like "must not use cookies from Amazon," that should be part of the question.  AFAIK, Amazon `<iframe>` will ALWAYS load an Amazon cookie, so if you don't want the cookie, you can't use an `<iframe>`.  You can make a static affiliate link to Amazon, but of course in that case you can't show the updated price in real time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know if you have the Amazon Partner API, it is possible to retrieve the price without loading third-party cookies ?

Comment: @Mathieu That's a Stack Overflow question and I don't know the answer.  But my guess would be that in exchange for giving you up-to-date information (and an affiliate commission), Amazon wants to track your users.